# Beep when volume go to 100

Tags: windows-10

Got a new Bluetooth speaker (JBL Clip 4). When I increase the volume to 100 (more precisely 96+), it beeps. How do I disable the beep?

I thought it was a "feature" of the speaker, but a Harman representative swore it's not.

My Windows sound scheme is set to None.